# React Onsenui - ons-navigator's page stack is empty (can't return to main page)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onsen-ui

Using Onsenui, I cannot pop a page after pushing it (to return to main/first page). From the first (already loaded) page, if I push one, then another, I can pop the last page (taking me back to the second page), but cannot pop the second page to go back to the very beginning.

The array length of this.props.navigator.pages is two prior to calling popPage(), yet it says the stack is empty, and won't let me return to the first page.

First Page:

```
import Nearest from './Nearest';    
export default class Dashboard extends Component {  
      pushPage = (component, name) => {
        this.props.navigator.pushPage({ component: component, props: { key: name } });
      }
      renderToolbar = () => {
        return (
          <Toolbar>
            <div className='center'>Your CoffeeSpots Dashboard</div>
          </Toolbar>
        );
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <Page renderToolbar={this.renderToolbar}>
            <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
              <Button key="nearestButton" onClick={() => this.pushPage(Nearest, "nearest")}>Nearest Coffee Shops</Button>
              <Button key="trendingButton" onClick={() => this.pushPage(Trending, "trending")}>Trending Local Coffee Shops</Button>
            </div>
          </Page>
        );
      }
```

Clicking on the button for "nearest" brings you to another page, but notably does not show the animation that "pushing" a page normally does.

"nearest" (second/onwards) page code:

```
export default class Nearest extends Component {
  popPage = () => {
    console.log(this.props.navigator.pages.length)
    this.props.navigator.popPage();
  }
  pushPage = () => {
    this.props.navigator.pushPage({ component: Nearest, props: { key: 'nearest2' } });
  }
  renderToolbar = () => {
    return (
      <Toolbar>
        <div className='center'>Nearest Coffee Shops</div>
      </Toolbar>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Page renderToolbar={this.renderToolbar}>
        <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
          <Button onClick={this.popPage}>
            Pop Page
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={this.pushPage}>
            Push Page
          </Button>
        </div>
      </Page>
    );
  }
}
```

Again, on this second page, clicking pop leaves an error that says the stack is empty, even though my console.log statement says that the stack has two objects.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution:

in my BottomNav component, I returned a  component, when you need to return a  so that the first element in the stack counts as a page, (making it not empty) - if the first element is a Tabbar, it counts as nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In other words, (AFAICT) you should always pushPage() components that have a Page as outermost tag